# Appearance of postnote (page, chapter, definition ...) in citation

Tags: biblatex, lncs

Using:

- LuaLaTeX
- Biber
- `biblatex`

  ```
  \usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,backend=biber,style=lncs]{biblatex}
  ```
- with the `lncs` style from  [from](https://github.com/gvdgdo/biblatex-lncs.git)

How can I create a citation that look like "[2](Def 5)" or "[2](ch 5)"?

When I use the command `\cite[Def 5]{ref-key}` the result is "[2, Def 5]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For output like this it makes sense to base the citation style on the citation style `numeric-verb`. Since `lncs.cbx` is just a wrapper around `numeric.cbx`, you can use `bibstyle=lncs, citestyle=numeric-verb`.

The only change of the `\cite` macro to the original in `numeric-verb.cbx` was the position of the brackets in the pre- and post-code arguments.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric-verb, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkbibparens{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \bibopenbracket}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}}{1}
     {\bibopenbracket}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite[380]{sigfridsson}

\cites[Chap.~5]{sigfridsson}[Thm.~4]{worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1](p. 380) [1](Chap. 5), [2](Thm. 4)]

If you are using an older version of `biblatex` you'll want to use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkbibparens{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}}
```

for the `postnote` format.